# Combining exception and error-code based class implementation

Tags: c++, exception, interface

I am writing a C++ class which has two different usage models. One is external, where we assume the user does not want any exceptions to be raised. Instead, error codes are returned. 
The other way of usage is internal, where I strive to avoid tedious error code checking and prefer to handle exceptions.

What would be a good way to combine the two approaches?

**Edit:**

- Both approaches may be used in the same binary
- Explicit is better than implicit
- Avoid exposing special constructs to user.

Comment: By `doesn't use exceptions` do you mean (1) they are not allowed as language constructs because, e.g. RTTI is disabled, or (2) the user just does not want to see them in their code? (2) would also affect your "internal" code.

Comment: (2). That's right, the internal code is always inside a `try-catch` block when used from within a public member function.

Comment: Well, if you go with 2 classes and the facade thingy you need to make sure that there is never a conversion between the base type and the derived type. You cannot have those functions virtual, as the return type is not going to be co-variant. I'd go with 3 classes. This will still be cumbersome because a `throw` point can be in the middle of a function and you will not be able to reuse code efficiently, but that's what you get.

Comment: @pmr, I meant 2 classes and composition, not inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two versions of the class, one which throws and one which returns error codes. They can both derive from a common base that contains the bulk of the code.

Comment: I thought about it. 1. Wouldn't it be too cumbersome to maintain 3 classes for this purpose. I have more than one class needing this kind of treatment. 2. Won't two classes suffice? One would serve as a facade for the other and would convert its exceptions to error codes.

Comment: @Albert, yes you could get by with two classes. I just thought it would be cleaner with three.

Comment: @Albert you could even do it with just one class and provide two different versions of each function, one that throws and one that doesn't. That seems even uglier, but it might serve better if the external program sometimes passes objects back into your library.

Comment: I think two classes would be cleaner. Less error prone for the user (the throwing function's interfaces are easier to use). If an external program would pass back those objects, then I would expose the throwing interface by cast or something. I would choose this approach if only some of the functions were like this. Similar to `std::vector`, `at` and `[]` accessors.

Answer (score 1):

I like Mark Ransom's answer better than mine, unless creating two classes is unworkable for some other reason.

As an alternative, you can create the interface so that every function has a final argument with a default, such as int *pRet = NULL.  If pRet == NULL that indicates to use exceptions.  If pRet != NULL, the caller has passed in a pointer that should be updated with an error code at the end of the function.

Internally in the functions, you need to catch exceptions, then either swallow them or re-throw them based on the pRet argument.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried such a thing, but here's what I would do.

Error type:

```
extern const bool exceptionmode;

enum error_codes {no_error, whatever};
struct error_type {
    error_codes id;
    //maybe also a non-owning const char* message?

    error_type() :id(no_error) {}
    error_type(error_codes code) :id(code) 
    {
        if (exceptionmode) throw_as_exception();
    }

    const char* get_as_string() {
        switch(id) {
        case whatever: return "out of bounds exception";
        case no_error: return "no error";
        default: return "unknown exception";
        }
    }
    void throw_as_exception() {
        switch(id) {
        case whatever: throw std::out_of_bounds("out of bounds exception");
        case no_error: break; //no error
        default: throw std::exception("unknown exception");
        }
    }

};
```

classes and functions:

```
class myclass {
public:        
    error_type my_member_function() {
         //stuff
         if (condition)
             return whatever;
         //more stuff
         return no_error;
    }
};
```

If you're really gutsy, you can make it so that the error_type class asserts if it never gets compared or converted or checked, to make sure nobody ever forgets to check the return value.

Comment: `extern const bool exceptionmode;` is too global. Both approaches may be used in the same binary. I could, however, provide this boolean argument in class constructor (or template argument) and use a factory (or template) to generate the error codes. I prefer explicit factory method call over implicit casting. It is clearer and the user needn't be aware of any special class. Just an enum or integer. What I dislike about this approach is that it always returns something, even in exception mode.

Comment: alright, well there's a lot of options. And yes, it always returns something, but in exceptionmode, it _always_ returns `no_error`, and so can be ignored.